# Stop Buzzer after some seconds/time?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-nano

This is a "water level alarm/display" sketch using and Arduino and ultrasonic sensor.
The buzzer gets on when the water level hits 100% or more.
But most of the time the water level will stay @ 100%, and I dont want the buzzer to run for long time.
How can I set the buzzer to make sound only for 15 seconds ?
It should turn off after 15 seconds, even if the water level is @ 100%

```
#define trigPin 8
#define echoPin 9
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int BUZZER = 10 ;

void setup(){
      int duration,distance,percentage,heightTank;
      Serial.begin (9600);
      pinMode(trigPin,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
      lcd.begin(16,2);
      lcd.print("HELLO");
        pinMode(BUZZER,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
      int duration,distance,percentage,heightTank,deviation;
      //You'll probably want to change the next 2 lines.
      // The first one is the max. level of the water.
      // The next one is how high the sensor is above that max. level.
      heightTank=65;
      deviation=4;

      digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
      digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
      duration=pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
      distance=(duration/2)/29.1;
      percentage=100-(((distance-deviation)*100)/heightTank);
      Serial.println(distance);
      Serial.println(percentage);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Current tank");
      //lcd.print(distance);
      //lcd.print(" cm");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("level: ");
      lcd.print(percentage);
      lcd.print(" %");
      delay(1000);

      digitalWrite(BUZZER,HIGH);
  if (percentage > 99) {digitalWrite(BUZZER,HIGH); delay(100); digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW); delay(100);}
  else  {digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW);}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at the end of `loop`

```
static unsigned long lastBuzzer = 0;

if(percentage > 99 && lastBuzzer == 0) {
    lastBuzzer = millis();
}

if(percentage > 99) {
    if(millis() - lastBuzzer < 15000L) {
        digitalWrite(BUZZER,HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW);
        delay(100);
    }
} else  {
    digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW);
    lastBuzzer = 0;
}
```

lastBuzzer is the last buzzer activation time (in ms). It's use to control that buzzing stop after 15 seconds. It's zero when the percentage is < 99; it's not zero when percentage >= 100.

(Not tested).
(Two `if's` instead of one for clarity).

Comment: May be nitpicking but... 0 is a perfectly valid return value for `millis()`, once every 49.7 days.

Comment: @EdgarBonet. True, but I can't see how it affects operation. If `millis` is zero in `lastBuzzer = millis();`, then `millis() - lastBuzzer` (both unsigned long) still will be `< 15000L`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to implement a *finite state machine*. This is a
very common paradigm in the embedded world. I recommend you start by
studying this tutorial: [The Finite State Machine](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/the-finite-state-machine/), by Majenko.

Four your particular problem, I would implement a machine with three
states: IDLE, ARMED and ALARM, the ALARM state being the only one in
which the buzzer is on. The transitions would be:

- ARMED → ALARM when the level hits 100%
- ALARM → IDLE after 15 seconds spent in the ALARM state
- IDLE → ARMED when the level gets below 90%

Note that the only difference between IDLE and ARMED is that the IDLE
state will not go into ALARM when the level reads 100%, as you have to
go through the ARMED state before. The threshold at 90% percent is meant
to add some [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). You can tweak the threshold value to your
taste.

I leave the implementation to you. It should be easy one you have
studied Majenko's tutorial.

---

**Edit**: Just to illustrate the generality of the concept, I would like
to point out that the code in Look Alterno's answer can be thought of as
a finite state machine where the state is implicitly encoded into the
variables `lastBuzzer` and `percentage`. The implicit state is:

- ARMED when lastBuzzer == 0
- ALARM when percentage > 99 && millis() - lastBuzzer < 15000L
- IDLE when  percentage > 99 && millis() - lastBuzzer >= 15000L

The line `lastBuzzer = 0` establishes the ARMED state as soon as
percentage ≤ 99. Note that this lacks hysteresis: if the reading
fluctuates between 99% and 100%, the alarm will sound again and again.

I personally prefer using an *explicit* state variable, as it makes the
code clearer to me. But then, the best approach is whichever makes the
code clearer *to you*.